# Created nested JSON from dynamic form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have a custom page builder for a client, where-by they can build out their own web forms via a drag and drop back-end.

At the moment, I can get the data to output in a JSON format such as the following:

```
{ 
  "email":"xx@yy.com",
  "geoip_country":"XXYY",
  "geoip_state":"XXYY",
  "geoip_city":"XXYY",
}
```

But, I need to alter the output in the following format, I'd like to seperate out the email field from the form, and drop all other data nested inside the dynamic_attributes section, like this:

```
{
    "email":"xx@yy.com",
    "dynamic_attributes":{
        "geoip_country":"XXYY",
        "geoip_state":"XXYY",
        "geoip_city":"XXYY",
        // all other form fields here.

    },
}
```

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I'm not hugely experienced with outputting JSON - I should also add that the json is being created from the following jQuery function:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {

        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name]) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

See Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fish_r/m46zLdo9/3/

Thanks!

Comment: Is `dynamic_attributes` a constant property name? If not where would that property name come from? How are fields separated as primary or children? Show some sample html

Comment: Both dynamic attributes and and the email are constant property names, the data nested within the dynamic attributes is what would be dynamically generated. Edited to add fiddle link

Comment: So it is a simple form and always has one primary field being `email` and all others are nested? I suspect there is a higher level of complexity than that no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```js
$('#myform').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serializeFormJSON();
    console.log(data);
});

(function ($) {
    $.fn.serializeFormJSON = function () {
  
        var o = {};
        var dynamic_attributes = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (this.name =='email') {
              if (o[this.name]) {
                  if (!o[this.name].push) {
                      o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                  }
                  o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
              } else {
                  o[this.name] = this.value || '';
              }
            } else {
              if (dynamic_attributes[this.name]) {
                  if (!dynamic_attributes[this.name].push) {
                      dynamic_attributes[this.name] = [dynamic_attributes[this.name]];
                  }
                  dynamic_attributes[this.name].push(this.value || '');
              } else {
                  dynamic_attributes[this.name] = this.value || '';
              }   
            }
        });
        o['dynamic_attributes'] = dynamic_attributes;
        
        return o;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.hidden {opacity:.3}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST" id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="name"><br/>
  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email"><br/>
  <input type="text" name="address1" placeholder="Enter the first line of your address"><br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing, Thank you - I've gained a good understanding of how we've created these from our vars at the top, I've gone ahead and created another property named extra_parameters, as we also need that for our integration. - One further question, do you know how I could possible exclude certain inputs by name/class or ID from being included?

Comment: Ignore that, I've managed to get this working by cloning the form in jquery, removing the hidden inputs and then running the serializeFormJSON() function. Thanks again Sunwoo.

Comment: I apologize for confirming the comments later. Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 0):

[To anyone looking for help on a similar issue in the future, I've created a library to allow forms to be sent as deep nested JSON objects by writing the `name` attributes of each input as a series of subkeys joined by "." characters.](https://github.com/rory660/deepforms)

To import the library:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/deepforms@1.0.0/deepforms.min.js"></script>
```

An example form made using the library:

```html
<form id = "exampleForm" method = "POST" action = "/submitForm">
    <input type = "text" name = "user.name" value = "testUser">
    <input type = "text" name = "color" value = "blue">
    <input type = "text" name = "color" value = "red">
</form>
<button onclick="document.deepforms.submitDeepForm('exampleForm')">
```

Upon clicking the submit button, the following object will be generated and sent as a JSON string:

```
{
    "user" : {
        "name" : "testUser"
    },
    "color" : ["blue", "red"]
}
```

The JSON string is sent as the value of a parameter called `deepFormJSON`:

```
deepFormJSON : '{"user":{"name":"testUser"},"color":["blue","red"]}}'
```

Which can be parsed as a JSON string in order to construct an object at the request destination.